# Process a file with 4000 lines using Java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, software-design

I am trying to process a 4000-line file with in 2 minutes using a java program. I cannot post the code here, but I’ll try my level best to describe it.

Processing of each line involves 2 sets of HTTP requests with each set containing 2 sequential/dependent HTTP requests. Each of these requests will take approximately 300 – 500 milli seconds. I need to compare the response of both the sets.

[image]

As depicted above, the sets are independent of each other. Hence, I decided to start each of them as two separate threads from a pool: internalExecutorService. Let’s call this process as LINE_PROCSSOR.

[image]

```
ExecutorService internalExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(90);
```

I need to deal with multiple such lines. So, each line is processed by different threads. Second thread pool (lineExecutorService) supplies threads for that. Let’s call this process as LINE_LIST_PROCESSOR

[image]

```
ExecutorService lineExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(40);
```

To deal with 4000 such lines, I decided to break them into chunks of 500 each. Then each chunk is processed in separate thread. A new thread pool was created for that. I will call it as chunkExecutorService.

[image]

```
ExecutorService chunkExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7);
```

The pool sizes are selected based on,

chunkExecutorService = 7.   I use a CPU with 8 cores. So decided to go with 7. 1 is for main thread. lineExecutorService = 40. Random select based on various runs. I ended up with stack error with more threads. internalExecutorService = 90. Just the double of above with some buffer threads as each line needs 2 threads.

I did a POC with the above setup. It did work locally. But I am not at all convinced with the way I have designed it and I believe my threads pool size selection doesn’t make any sense. It may not work well when deployed to server.
[Note: I did not opted for java parallel streams as I felt ExecutorService gives better handle of thread pool].
I haven't worked with threads extensively, so I am looking for an expert advice from you to evaluate my design and suggest if there are better ways to deal with it.

*************** UPDATE **************

This is a server side application that will have to deal with concurrent (1-5 requests at the same time) file processing requests.

Comment: Nice images and explanation, but I think your question is a bit too broad

Comment: You should avoid distracting yourself with irrelevant details. The file and its 4000 lines are irrelevant. Your question is about dealing with 4000×4 HTTP requests. There is no point in breaking the file into chunks or use threading policies aligned at the CPU cores when your actual task is about I/O. And it’s entirely unclear what stack error you got with more threads.

Comment: I think It is..  because every line has unavoidable 4 http requests and I cannot execute the lines sequentially. I don't exactly remember the stack error, but when I googled it I realized it is because of the thread count more than what system can handle.

Comment: You did it again. So I have to tell you again, your issue is “*dealing with 4000×4 HTTP requests*”. It doesn’t matter whether your program sends these HTTP requests while processing lines of a text file or because little gnomes from Alpha Centauri told it to do so. You keep focusing on the irrelevant thing and are over-complicating the design. On the other hand, you did not post anything about the relevant operation. How do you send these HTTP requests, just using `URL`, using the builtin `HttpClient`, or a 3rd party library? Some frameworks do already deal with concurrency and load balancing.

Comment: I use Spring RestTemplate backed by apache HttpClient. I am still not clear on the concurrency that we can apply on HTTPClient. All 4 Http calls are not independent.

Answer (score 4):

If you need four different diagrams to convey a solutation for iterating a file and doing two http requests per line, your solution might be excessively complicated ...

Rather than trying to prune the excess complexity, let's take this from other direction: Start with the simplest possible implementation, and make it more complicated until it meets the performance target.

The simplest solution is this:

```
for (var line : lines) {
    var data = parse(line);
    var firstResponse = firstCall(data);
    var secondResponse = secondCall(data);
    var c = compare(firstResponse, secondResponse);
    var result = ...;
}
```

This solution has an execution time of 4000 * (0.5 + 0.5) = 4000 seconds. The big multiplier is the 4000, so let's tackle that:

```
var executor = ...;
var futures = new ArrayList<Future<Result>>();
for (var line : lines) {
    var data = parse(line);
    futures.add(executor.submit(() -> {
        var firstResponse = firstCall(data);
        var secondResponse = secondCall(data);
        var c = compare(firstResponse, secondResponse);
        return ...;
    }));
}

for (var future : futures) {
    var result = future.get();
    // do something with result
}
```

This code had execution time (0.5 + 0.5) seconds, if you have enough threads to send 4000 requests in parallel. In practice, the limiting factor will be the other system.

And so, we are done. There is no need to parse the data in separate threads, because parsing is fast. There is no need to send the two requests in separate threads, because it only buys us half a second.

In sizing the executor, we'll want to ensure that we don't overwhelm the other system. It might be advisable to ask whoever is operating these services how many requests per second you're allowed to send, and then pick a thread number in a safe range.

(If the file were too large to fit into memory, you would need to ensure that only a limited number of lines is being processed at a time, streaming both the file and response. But since 4000 lines easily fit into memory, that's not necessary here)

Comment: Yes, that make sense. But one concern I have is, this application might have to deal with 1-5 concurrent requests. It's still a worst case scenario, but I want the system to be capable of handling that. That's one of the reason I thought of coming up with some shared thread pools. Do you think dedicating all 4000 threads to a single request might overflow the thread stack?

Comment: That's not the way that thread stacks work!   But yes, 4000 threads would clearly be a problem.  So just use a bounded thread pool executor service ... with a *reasonable* number of threads.  (The value of "reasonable" can be determined by testing and tuning.)

Comment: Yes, if you process several files concurrently, you should share the thread pool rather than creating a new one for each request (the size limit on the thread pool protects the other systems from being overloaded, and the capacity of these systems is independent of how many requests your system gets).

Comment: @StephenC can you please put some light on what you meant by "That's not the way that thread stacks work!". Feel like that's what I am missing.

Comment: Well for a start ... how would you dedicate 4000 client-side threads to a single HTTP request?  How would it even work?   But the real point is that each thread has its own stack.  What one thread does cannot overflow any other thread's stack (in any practical use-case).  Stack overflow is caused by recursing too deeply *within a single thread*.  Now having 4000 threads is a problem because that means there are 4000 stacks of the default stack size ... and that uses a lot of memory.  But having too many threads (hence stacks) leads to an OOME not an SOE.

Comment: @StephenC Yes. I saw OOME intermittently and never saw an SOE. Unable to reproduce it now, but something like "Stack size of 2056 Kb exceeds current limit of 2048 Kb." when I had too many un controlled threads. So do you think a shared thread pool (like what I have) with a detailed tuning exercise to set the pool size will work?

Comment: See my first comment for my answer to that.